# Descartar valores que se repiten segun criterio - Python

Tags: python, pandas

tengo el sigueinte df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','c','a','b','c'], 'col2': [1,2,3,1,5,3]})
```

Y quiero descartar los duplicados de `col1` que no tengan el mismo valor en `col2` cada vez que aparecen. Resultado esperado:

```
 col1 col2
0  a   1
1  c   3
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agrupar por `col1` y aplicar `pandas.Series.nunique` para obtener un filtro boleano que marque los valores de `col1` (grupo) que tiene un solo valor en `col2`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
    'col2': [1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3]}
    )

new = (df.set_index("col1")[df.groupby("col1")["col2"].nunique() == 1]
         .drop_duplicates()
         .reset_index()
         )
```

> ```
> >     >>> new
> >       col1  col2
> >     0    a     1
> >     1    c     3
> ```